# Less distance subsubsection in cleanthesis style

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, cleanthesis

How can I reduce the distance between the subsubsection heading and the text in the Clean Thesis Style? I didn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out: One have to add/change the following in the cleanthesis.sty

```
% > formats: \subsubsection
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]
```

It's the value in the {after-sep}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes, it uses the `titlesec` package. You can take a look at the latter package documentation, if you have some other fine-tuning to do for your layout.